# ASP.NET Required Field Validator not working

Tags: asp.net, field, validation, required

Hi all I need a required field validator for my textbox..This is my textbox..

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTimeSlotGroupName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" 
     ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>  
<font color="red">*</font>  
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_txtTimeSlotGroupName"
     runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTimeSlotGroupName" Display="None"
     ErrorMessage="Timeslot Group Required!" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="0"
     ValidationGroup="TimeSlot"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

**My button:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddTimeSlots" Text="Add Timeslots" CssClass="button" 
     runat="server" OnClick="btnAddTimeslots_Click" ValidationGroup="TimeSlot" 
     OnClientClick="javascript:shouldsubmit=true;"/>
```

I am not getting the error message. Any solutions?

Comment: Need to put `ValidationGroup` to `txtTimeSlotGroupName` :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to define the Validation Group Of your `Textbox` too....to make it work

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtTimeSlotGroupName" runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="false" ValidationGroup="TimeSlot" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 9):

Remove InitialValue="0"  from the RequiredFieldValidator tag, it is not required when you are validating the textbox.

Answer (score 7):

Even I was facing the same issue. Kindly check if any javascript are present on your page.  Irrespective of above make use of `Page.Validate()` method and `if(Page.IsValid)` in your code. This will automatically force your validation controls and issue will be solved

Answer (score 3):

If two objects have the same id the required field validator Does not work.

Comment: Can you clarify? "Objects" do not have an "id" - do you mean names for variables? If so, from which context? Or, perhaps you mean the "id" attribute of an element? If so, which elements? Do you mean any elements on the page with the same id will break validation? I doubt that, but that's the closest I can come to interpreting this answer. Thank you in advance for any additional detail you can provide!!

Comment: Late to the party but CHEGNI means any element on the page. A text box, a required field validator, a buton, a custom validator, ANYTHING. Any two elements that have id="idname". if any two have the same ID then some things can go wrong, especially in javascript.

Comment: @CHEGENI is right? any solution for this after 6 years

Answer (score 1):

You just add ValidationGroup="TimeSlot" in textbox

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTimeSlotGroupName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" 
   ValidationGroup="TimeSlot"   ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

*I had this same issue... but none of the above answers were the fix for me...*

My problem was that I was missing the `Page.isValid` in my button press method.  Below is my button code and the method called by the button.

**Button:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBtmSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" BtnGroup="save" TabIndex="18" />
```

**Button method:**

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        //Logic goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make the same Validation Group Of all your text and Add button and Validation

```
   ValidationGroup="AAA"
```

and add the code to your save button:

```
  If (Page.IsValid) Then
        YOURSQL.Insert()
   'or ur code here'
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, For button, I was using both client side validation i.e onClientClick="return validate()", and ASP.NET Validation i.e Reguired field Validation (ValidationGroup). Hence the Required field validators were not firing.